# Android php mysql, do not operate with log

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I have made application : mysql <-> Android using php.

I success to mysql with php.

http://localhost/phptest/newfile.php

> id: jogi - password: 1234
>
> id: jogi1 - password: 12341
>
> id: jogi2 - password: 12342

but i have some trouble with connet Android.

Some code's are ignored. and does not message on log.
also android AVD not stopped but do not show any change. console do not show error, too... What can i do? or How can i check errors?

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.phpmysql;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  private TextView result;

   @Override 
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);      
      result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view1);    
   }

   public void Show_list(View view){
       new SigninActivity(this,result,0).execute(); 
   }
}
```

SigninActivity.java

```
package com.example.phpmysql;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SigninActivity  extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{
   private TextView resultField; //statusField
   private int byGetOrPost = 0; 

   public SigninActivity(Context context,TextView resultField,int flag) {
      byGetOrPost = flag;
   }

   protected void onPreExecute(){

   }

   @Override
   protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
       String  myResult = null; //initiate;

      if(byGetOrPost == 0){ //means by Get Method
          Log.d("flag","0");
          try { 
              URL url = new URL("http://http://localhost/phptest/newfile.php");   
              HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();   
              Log.d("where","http connect");


              http.setDefaultUseCaches(false);                                            
              http.setDoInput(true);                         
              http.setDoOutput(true);                       
              http.setRequestMethod("POST");         
              http.setRequestProperty("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
              Log.d("where","property");
              //-------------------------- 

              InputStreamReader tmp = new InputStreamReader(http.getInputStream(), "EUC-KR");
              BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(tmp); 
              StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(); 
              String str;
              Log.d("where","inputstream");
              while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null) {       
                   builder.append(str + "\n");                     
              } 
              myResult = builder.toString();                       
              Log.d("myresult",myResult);
             return myResult;

         } catch (MalformedURLException e) { 
                // 
         } catch (IOException e) { 
                //  
         } // try 

      }
      else{

      }
    return myResult;
   }

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(String result){
      if(result != null)
          this.resultField.setText(result);
      else
          Log.d("failed", "postfailed");
   }
}
```

This is all of my log. only one error when open but i think that AVD is connect well so it is not important.
A curious thing is that I can't find "input stream" with tag "where" in SigninActivity.java;

> 08-16 07:31:48.603: E/Trace(772): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
>
> 08-16 07:31:49.753: D/gralloc_goldfish(772): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
>
> 08-16 07:32:55.214: D/flag(772): 0
>
> 08-16 07:32:55.224: D/where(772): http connect
>
> 08-16 07:32:55.224: D/where(772): property
>
> 08-16 07:32:55.417: D/failed(772): postfailed

no error with application starting. If click the button 'list', no error, no stop also but no any change view. just white blank screen.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >



<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="26dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button2"
    android:onClick="Show_list"
    android:text="@string/Show_List" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view1" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: localhost wont work on it....you need to give you computers ip address

Comment: P.S : original code is exist 'button2' . but it is with no implement. so i erase uploading code  'button 2', with xml.

Comment: but i can check with chrome  "http://localhost/phptest/newfile.php"

Comment: localhost is for you computer and you are running your android app on either emulator or phone... so localhost wont work.

Comment: what is mean to "i give computer ip address"?

Comment: if you are using router then give your local ip like 192.168.X.X/phptest/newfile.php

Comment: I think that I should change mysql's grant and confirm my address with 'cmd-> ipconfig'. that's right?

Comment: yes... if you are using router

Comment: thank you! i will try soon!

Comment: oh it does work! although i have some errors... haha....;;
Thank you. i try fix other error myself!! ^ -^

Answer (score 0):

you are not directly talking to mysql , your android app will receive a response from the webserver and so you need to call the webserver accessible url . 
If you are in a local network give the webserver local address in

```
 URL url = new URL("http://{webserverURL}/phptest/newfile.php");
```

You can get the IP from apache installed machine using ipconfig (Windows), ifconfig (linux).